# How to get nested records with has_many :through association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, join, associations

```
class Manager < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :bands
end

class Band < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :manager
  has_many :member_bands
  has_many :members, through: :member_bands
end

class Member < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :member_bands
  has_many :bands, through: :member_bands
end

class MemberBand < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :member
  belongs_to :band
end
```

What I'm ultimately trying to do is get all of the Members for a given Manager.

I feel like there's some set of joins I need to do, but having trouble nailing that down.

I've tried `manager.bands.joins(:members)` but I just get multiple `bands` and no members.

I'm hacking this together with multiple loops at the moment:

```
manager.bands.each do |band|
  band.members.each do |member|
    ##
  end
end
```

So, how can I get all of the `members` associated with a given `manager` (who are connected via the `bands`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your associations, you should be able to just add

```
has_many :members, through: :bands
```

to your Manager.

```
irb(main):003:0> Manager.first.members
  Manager Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "managers".* FROM "managers" ORDER BY "managers"."id" ASC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
  Member Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  "members".* FROM "members" INNER JOIN "member_bands" ON "members"."id" = "member_bands"."member_id" INNER JOIN "bands" ON "member_bands"."band_id" = "bands"."id" WHERE "bands"."manager_id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["manager_id", 1], ["LIMIT", 11]]
=> #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<Member id: 1>, #<Member id: 2>, #<Member id: 3>, #<Member id: 5>, #<Member id: 6>, #<Member id: 7>]>
```

Comment: That was far too easy. :) Worked perfectly. Thank you!